# I am getting "Unsupported operation: -infinity" as an error in Flutter. Where is this issue happening?

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to render Mapbox into my Flutter Web app. I keep getting this error in Flutter which I am not sure as to what is happening exactly.

[image]
I have posted the image here of the error

This is the library that I am using to render Mapbox. I am not sure at what is happening unfortunately.
https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl

I would love it if someone gave me a direction or a suggestion as to what is happening here. Any answer or helpful suggestion would be much appreciated! :)

Edit: Here is the code for this

```
class _MapTabState extends State<MapTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FlutterMap(
            options: MapOptions(
              center: latlng.LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
              zoom: 9.2,
            ),
            children: [
              TileLayer(
                urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                additionalOptions: {
                  'accessToken': 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamF6aWx6YWltMzIiLCJhIjoiY2w3NTg3Z3IyMXA4cDNubXE0N2Rsdm5jaCJ9.oOhMWI2U3gJf3-Jszw-5NA',
                  'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-bathymetry-v2'
                },
              ),
            ],
            nonRotatedChildren: [
              RichAttributionWidget(
                attributions: [
                  TextSourceAttribution(
                    'OpenStreetMap contributors',
                    onTap: () => launchUrl(
                        Uri.parse('https://openstreetmap.org/copyright')),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using MapBox to do the rendering?  Please include the code.

Comment: Infinity errors generally mean the widget expected restraints and it received none. Why this is happening depends entirely on your code.

Comment: I have just included the code. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Yeah, you put the widget in an unbounded `Column`, which means it has infinity height. You don't have any other children of the `Column` either, so I'd say just get rid of it as it's not serving a purpose.

Comment: I wrapped my FlutterMap around a constrained box and gave it a height and width which solved the issue.

Comment: Maintainer of flutter_map here: mapbox_gl != flutter_map! You are using a `FlutterMap` widget to display Mapbox tiles - that's not the same as using mapbox_gl to display a Mapbox map. I also want to warn you that, if you are still using the above code, you are likely breaking Mapbox's attribution requirements!

Comment: Ahh thank you. What is the best way to add attribution? I'd appreciate any links or code samples! :)